# My sum panel not working on the way? Overlapping issue?

Tags: php, html, css

What I want to do: I am a beginner trying to learn PHP.

**Why can't I click on the *"input panel"* and *"submit panel"* in the second sum operation?**

I've tried adding `z-index` to every single `<input>`, but it's still not working.

```html
<h1>SUM</h1>

<style>
  .circle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  #input1{
    width: 30%;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  #submit1{
    z-index: 100;
  }
  .result {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: blue;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index:1;
  }
</style>

<div class="circle">
  <form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input id='input1'  type="number" name="number" placeholder="100">
    <input id='submit1' type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
  
  <?php
  if(isset($_GET['number'])) {
    $total = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $_GET['number']; $i++) {
      $total += $i;
    }
    echo "<div class='result'>{$total}</div>";
  }
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the outcome you expect and what do you see instead? You code does exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Add `background: blue;` to `.result`, and the issue should become apparent real quick. Or learn to use your browser dev tools, right click + "inspect" in the position where you expected a click to do something, but it doesn't - then you'll see what you _actually_ clicked on, in the elements panel.

Comment: Why is there absolute positioning involved here to begin with?

Comment: Thank you for your help!! The effect I want is the code itself. Clicking "submit" will display the value of "sum" in the circular "div". The problem now is that everything is normal when I click it for the first time. , but when you click "submit" for the second or third time, the mouse pointer will not be able to find the button.

Comment: The code is error-free. Could you please clarify your intention with this code?

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP itself?

Comment: This sounds like an issue me and my coworkers used to have in Chrome, when clicking on an element, followed by a page refresh, does not detect the hover when the mouse is not first moved. The code itself is valid, can you try after submitting the form, to move your cursor around before clicking the button again?

Comment: the solution was given.. did you see that as absolute positioned, the `.result` div is covering the area containing the input field and the button?